# How do I get the user's ID with discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a bot that makes a to do list for each user who uses it. I want each user to get their own file to store the list in, but I'm confused how to actually get the user ID.

```py
@client.command()
async def todo(ctx, arg1, *args):
    todoArray =open(UserId,'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) [passed as the first argument to the command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#commands) has an [`author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.author) attribute that's shorthand for [`Context.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.message) and [`Message.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author), and [`User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User) objects have an [`id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.id) attribute.
So in this case, you can simply use `ctx.author.id` to get the ID of the user that sent the command message.